# jQuery AJAX Post - encoding

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, encoding

I am posting form from page in UTF-8 to page in Win-1250. I have problem with chars encoding.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: $(this).serializeArray()
});
```

Comment: have you assigned appropriate charset to your form as well?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? You've given hardly any information to go on.

Comment: After that, when I am selecting data from database, the chars are broken. I don't have chance to change encoding in connection to database.

I am posting "ěščřžýáíé" and result is "Ä›ĹˇÄŤĹ™ĹľĂ˝ĂˇĂ­Ă©".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At server - side script you can use something like that:

```
$res = array();
foreach($_POST as $p)
{
    array_push($res,iconv('UTF-8','Windows-1250',$p));
}
```

`$res` - is encoded array

Comment: Yes, but backend is in Java and I don't have chance to change anything.

Comment: Maybe you can put your request and request data in iframe where you can set the right encoding;